# How to copy git workspace with change list & history to another system?

Tags: git, android-studio

Recently we are moved from SVN to git. When we were working with SVN, if I copy(archive and copy) the whole code base(with .svn folder) to some other machine, and do some changes, only the newly modified files will be shown in the change list. Hence I can directly commit to SVN from the new machine.

But with git, after copying the workspace with .git files to some other machine, I could see the history of the branch in the new machine but all the files are shown as modified files. 
It asks me to add all files as a new one!

Did I miss any git files to copy? How to achieve the same as in SVN which I explained above.

Comment: You did include the .git folder, right?

Comment: Yes of course! I could also see all the contents inside the .git folder in the new machine!

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or something else which shows this? What does `git diff` show?

Comment: Do you copy from Windows to Linux or vice versa?

Comment: Yup, I am copying from mac to windows & mac to ubuntu! I am preparing the screenshots, will add those shortly.

Comment: Did you consider [this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)?

Comment: That is interesting! Thanks.. If my understanding is right, mac to ubuntu should work right?

Comment: I have core.autocrlf = input in my git config file.